# Reduce idle current consumption of 28byj-48 stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I have a question to ask. I'm using this stepper motor and found out that even the motor stop to the desired position, it still feeling hot and I guess it still consuming the same current as it move. But is that a way to reduce it? Don't tell me to choose pricey stepper motor because I want to use low cost to do this project. Thanks.

Comment: Your stepper motor drive may permit you to command it to disable the current entirely or to reduce it during pauses between movements, but depending on your application this mean that the motor can be mechanically disturbed out of position.  And of course you can make sure that your ordinary current is not excessive; hopefully you are using a chopping driver.   You could also conceivably use a cooling fan, however the parts of the motor where heat is an issue may be hotter than the case.   As it stands this question is a bit broad to fit here.  At least edit in the identity of the driver.

Comment: I use common ULN2003 driver to drive it but since I used it with arduino, I guess I found a library that can reduce the overall power consumption of the project. Need to test it out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motor current, and therefore its heat, is determined by the stepper driver and the supply voltage.

To reduce power you need to reduce current by decreasing voltage during standby or by reducing the current by some means such as PWM.